# std::remove_pointer can not remove the const volatile function pointer on VS2012

Tags: c++, stl

`std::remove_pointer` can not remove the const volatile function pointer on VS2012
is this a buf in vs2012?

```
#include "iostream"
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef void (* const cfunp_t) ();

    cout<<typeid(cfunp_t).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(std::remove_pointer<cfunp_t>::type).name()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output build by vs2012 :

```
void (__cdecl*)(void)
void (__cdecl*)(void)         // can not remove the const function pointer
```

output build by mingw gcc 4.7.2

```
PFvvE
FvvE                          // can remove the const function pointer
```

Comment: Can you add an actual comparison of the `typeid`s, not just their printable names?

Comment: The point of Kerrek's question being: maybe VS2012 has removed the pointer from the type, but for some reason the names of the typeids of function types in VS2012 include the `*` anyway. If so that might still be a bug but it wouldn't violate the standard.

Answer (score 0):

thank all

i change my test code :

```
#include "iostream"
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

typedef void fun_t();
typedef fun_t* funp_t;
typedef const funp_t cfunp_t;

template<typename T>
void print_type()
{
    cout<<"unknow"<<endl;
}

template<>
void print_type<fun_t>()
{
    cout<<"is a function"<<endl;
}

template<>
void print_type<funp_t>()
{
    cout<<"is a function pointer"<<endl;
}

template<>
void print_type<cfunp_t>()
{
    cout<<"is a const function pointer"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    print_type<cfunp_t>();
    print_type<std::remove_pointer<cfunp_t>::type>();

    return 0;
}
```

an the output :

in vs2012

```
is a const function pointer

is a const function pointer
```

in gcc

```
is a const function pointer

is a function
```